# button cannot be seen even though set visibility android

Tags: android

I have a searchview and button next to it. And the button is make as visible GONE. when typing something on searchview I want to show the button. My problem is it is not showing the button properly even though i make the visibility to VISIBLE.

```
svSearchSentItem.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            preLast = 0;
            isQuickSearch = true;
            currentMailInboxListMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            setSentItemListView(query, 0, 50, true,false);
            ((DashboardActivity)getActivity()).mailSentSearchQuery=query;
            searchCycle = 1;
            svSearchSentItem.clearFocus();


            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (newText.isEmpty()) {

            }
            else
            {
                btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

XML layout

```
LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:weightSum="8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/layoutSearch">

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/svMailSent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:hint="Search"

            android:autoText="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:queryHint="Search"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSentSearchClear"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you call findViewById for your Button?

Comment: put a break point at this `btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` line, Debug the app and see if it is reaching there or not..!!

Answer (score 0):

U can use ajax with android to check if the searchview is empty or not, if it is not empty then make view.visible else view.gone.

http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-ajax-auto-load

this might help!

Answer (score -1):

sorry but you cant use those 3 properties together in this way  :)

```
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
```

when you use layout_weight you need set one of property: height or width to 0dp:

```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

weight (float weight)

> Indicates how much of the extra space in the LinearLayout will be allocated to the view associated with these LayoutParams. Specify 0 if the view should not be stretched. Otherwise the extra pixels will be pro-rated among all views whose weight is greater than 0.

i propose you to delete all properties and first set only:

- id
- width
- height

if it you will see what u want then you can add some extra properties this way you will see when it fails :)

use this and report result :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutSearch"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="8">
    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/svMailSent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSentSearchClear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

*@ceph3us, I changed the layout as you suggested. But still I can't see the button. It seems that it is going right corner outside the screen – creative Pro*

**you are embedding badly the child view, or your parent is erroneously defined**

[image]

**and don't use "fill_parent"** from api 8 is depreciated - btw os'es with api's < 8 are almost dead :)

> LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;

```
public static class LayoutParams {
    /**
     * Special value for the height or width requested by a View.
     * FILL_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
     * minus the parent's padding, if any. This value is deprecated
     * starting in API Level 8 and replaced by {@link #MATCH_PARENT}.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    @Deprecated
    public static final int FILL_PARENT = -1;
 ...
}
```

*It didn't help changing anything in XML layout. I found this solution instead. In the oncreateview, I get the layoutparams and assign it in the onQueryTextSubmit event in searchview.
oldLayoutParams = svSearchSentItems.getLayoutParams();*

### YEAH BUDDY YOU ROCK!!!

**copy paste does not require understanding - i wish to have more developers like you :)**

see this is what you trying to do:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    final View btnClear = findViewById(R.id.btnSentSearchClear);
    SearchView sv = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.svMailSent);
    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            btnClear.setVisibility(newText!=null 
                && !newText.isEmpty() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

**FULL WORKING ANDROID STUDIO EXAMPLE ON GITHUB**

https://github.com/c3ph3us/exampleHideButtonForSearchView/

Comment: i think `android:layout_height` should be `wrap_content`, because orientation of parent `LinearLayout` is horizontal.

Comment: I changed as follows. Didn't help. android:layout_width="130dp"   
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"

Comment: @creative-pro u need to do this for  SearchView & Button

Comment: @ceph3us, I changed the layout as you suggested. But still I can't see the button. It seems that it is going right corner outside the screen

Comment: @creativePro -  post parent layout

Answer (score -1):

It didn't help changing anything in XML layout. I found this solution instead. In the oncreateview, I get the layoutparams and assign it in the onQueryTextSubmit event in searchview.

oldLayoutParams = svSearchSentItems.getLayoutParams();

```
svSearchSentItem.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        preLast = 0;
        isQuickSearch = true;
        currentMailInboxListMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        setSentItemListView(query, 0, 50, true,false);
        ((DashboardActivity)getActivity()).mailSentSearchQuery=query;
        searchCycle = 1;
        svSearchSentItem.clearFocus();
        svSearchSentItem.setLayoutParams(oldLayoutParams);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (newText.isEmpty()) {

        }
        else
        {
            btnClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```